# libSOIL.a file is getting ignored on MacOS

Tags: macos, opengl, makefile, cmake, soil

I installed SOIL on my Mac (BigSur) in the normal way with make and make install. When I do `cmake .` to my OpenGL Project, everything is ok and SOIL is found. But when i do `make`, i get following warning/error: `ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libSOIL.a, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64`.
I tried everything i found on the internet. I also included -m64 in the Makefile.
Does somebody know to solve this issue?

Comment: The linker builds for `macOS-x86_64` but ignores the file which is built **exactly for this platform**.. Are you sure that you get exactly this error message?

Answer (score 1):

libSOIL uses the [Carbon API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_(API)) ([see here](https://github.com/childhood/libSOIL/blob/master/SOIL.c#L26)). The Carbon API has been deprecated with Montain Lion and removed with Catalina. I have removed libSOIL from a project for this reason, it is unlikely you can get it to work without rewriting some of its code.

A possible replacement would be [libSDL](https://libsdl.org) along with [SDL_image](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/). These libs are much more heavy-weight, but can be used while still doing raw OpenGL rendering and ignoring the SDL rendering API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SOIL2` replace `libSOIL`, see [SOIL2](https://github.com/SpartanJ/SOIL2) for more.

Comment: SOIL2 still [depends on the Carbon API](https://github.com/SpartanJ/SOIL2/blob/master/src/SOIL2/SOIL2.c#L78) and so isn't a valid replacement for modern macOS.

Comment: But I can use this package to build simple OpenGL program..